# idiomatic way to lexically scope variables in a cl-loop body

Tags: lexical-scoping, common-lisp, iteration

Here is some asynchronous code in a `cl-loop`:

```
;;; foo.el ---                              -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do (run-at-time 0 nil
                           (lambda () (message "index=%s,value=%s" index value)))))
```

This code prints `"index=3,value=c"` 3 times in the `*Messages*` buffer. This is not what I want. I would like to see `"index=0,value=a"`, `"index=1,value=b"`, `"index=2,value=c"` (I don't care about the order of messages).

A workaround is to let-bind the `index` and `value` variables:

```
;;; foo.el ---                              -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do (let ((index index) (value value))
                (run-at-time 0 nil
                             (lambda () (message "index=%s,value=%s" index value))))))
```

This is good enough for me but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Another workaround is to pass `#'message` as third argument to `run-at-time` instead of the `lambda` and to pass the arguments to `message` as `&rest` arguments to `run-at-time`. This is not good enough for me though because my [real code](https://gitlab.petton.fr/DamienCassou/navigel/blob/v0.3.0/navigel.el#L173) is a bit more complex and involves calling a callback variable which may or may not do a `run-at-time`.

Comment: IMO, your workaround would be the idiomatic way to get lexically scoped variables (in fact all the variables are already lexical, you just need a narrower scope).

Comment: By the way, `for value = (seq-elt my-list index)` is [O(n^2)](https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/), you should probably use `for value in my-list` instead.

Comment: Regarding the use of `seq-elt`, I agree with you. I've just asked a new question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52251/iterate-with-both-value-and-index

Comment: Given your real code, I think a more representative example would use `collect (lambda () (message "value%s" value))` and then funcall the returned lambdas outside the loop. But that would invalidate @Tobias' answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the timer runs the function when the loop has finished.
The lexically bound variables `index` and `value` have for all calls the values after the last iteration.

One solution is to evaluate the variables at iteration time and pass just the values as arguments to the function.

```el
(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do (run-at-time 0 nil
                           (lambda (index value) (message "index=%s,value=%s" index value))
               index value)))
```

With that method you could even free the function from its lexical environment:

```el
(defun my-out (index value)
  (message "index=%s,value=%s" index value))

(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do (run-at-time 0 nil
               #'my-out
               index value)))
```

Comment: I like this answer best; although as the desired code "may or may not do a run-at-time", I'd suggest a slightly more generalised variant of "define external function accepting two arguments, and call it directly in the loop with: `do (my-func index value)`

Comment: I have edited my question with a link to the real code so you see what I meant with "involves calling a callback variable which may or may not do a run-at-time".

Comment: @DamienCassou In your real code, the `run-at-time` part doesn't use `index` or `value`, so it's not really relevant (and you can't use this answer).  Also, you only need to re-bind `index`, since `item` is used immediately.

Comment: @npostavs I think the lambda itself is the problem. One does not know when the lambda is called (indirectly) through `mapfn`. It may be that `mapfn` also uses `run-at-time` for the call of the lambda.

Comment: @Tobias indeed, `mapfn` may call its callback long after it has returned. That's the whole purpose of the `async-map` function I'm writing.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use backquoting to substitute the values for each loop iteration directly into the lambda form:

```el
;;; foo.el ---                              -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do (run-at-time 0 nil
                           `(lambda () (message "index=%s,value=%s" ',index ',value)))))
```

But really, the approach you came up with yourself (i.e. to create lexical variables within each iteration) is probably the way to go.

This is, after all, a case of the classic "how do I create/fake a closure in elisp" question, and the idiomatic answer when lexical-binding is enabled *is* to use a `let` binding.

You *don't* need to repeat the same names for the inner variables, though -- and perhaps you'd find it less inelegant if you weren't doing that?

Comment: If `run-at-time` would not allow for any arguments of the callback backquoting would be the best. +1 for the general approach.

Comment: I have edited my question with a link to the real code so you see what I meant with "involves calling a callback variable which may or may not do a run-at-time".

Comment: I actually prefer having the same names in the `let` because it makes the workaround more explicit IMO.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a macro:

```
(defmacro lexical-save (vars &rest body)
  `(lexical-let ,(mapcar (lambda (var) (list var var)) vars)
     ,@body))
```

You can use it is follows:

```
(let ((my-list '(a b c)))
  (cl-loop for index below (length my-list)
           for value = (seq-elt my-list index)
           do
           (run-at-time
            0 nil
            (lexical-save (index value)
                          (lambda () (insert (format "index=%s,value=%s\n" index value)))))))
```

I altered your example to let it insert text instead of using `message`, in order to better see what it's doing. Run it in the `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: I like it because the solution is a bit more explicit than what I did. It will help my future me understand :-).